# Rails Paperclip: do something after attachment is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip with Rails for saving attachments. I need to do something after the attachment is saved. The problem is that after_photo_post_process (as well as after_post_process) is called before the attachment is actually resized and saved.

Here is the code:

```
after_photo_post_process :update_facebook
#after_create :update_facebook

    def update_facebook
    puts "UPDATE_FACEBOOK"
    puts item_id.to_s
        if(!@graph)
            @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(User.find(Item.find(item_id).user_id).fbprofile.access_token)
        end

        options = {
            :message => "I've just added " + Item.find(item_id).title + " to my 111 items list. Check it out: http://111items.com/items/" + item_id.to_s,
            :picture => "http://localhost:3000" + photo.url(:small),
            :link => "http://111items.com/items/" + item_id.to_s
            }

        puts options

        @graph.put_object("me", "feed", options)
    end
```

And here is a server output:

```
UPDATE_FACEBOOK
157
{:message=>"I've just added calculator to my 111 items list. Check it out: http://111items.com/items/157", :picture=>"http://localhost:3000/system/photos/21/small/casio_fx-82sx.jpg?1329477882", :link=>"http://111items.com/items/157"}


Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-17 13:24:42 +0200
  Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xbDLXeQlld/fDa7bZQZPhzr+OHUAYvFgH1h/CTNCLIQ=", "item"=>{"title"=>"calculator", "description"=>"", "public"=>"1", "secure_details"=>"", "bookmark_id"=>"152", "warranty_until"=>"", "assets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004b89d78 @original_filename="casio_fx-82sx.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"item[assets_attributes][0][photo]\"; filename=\"casio_fx-82sx.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120217-8212-1a67ce6>>}}}, "commit"=>"Create Item"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 30 LIMIT 1
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/stream20120217-8212-i7zn7g.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/tmp/stream20120217-8212-i7zn7g.jpg[0]' -resize "80x" -crop "80x80+0+13" +repage '/tmp/stream20120217-8212-i7zn7g20120217-8212-m4rkbm' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/stream20120217-8212-i7zn7g.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/tmp/stream20120217-8212-i7zn7g.jpg[0]' -resize "150x150>" '/tmp/stream20120217-8212-i7zn7g20120217-8212-14hjb17' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving /home/alex/hundredthings/public/system/photos/21/original/casio_fx-82sx.jpg
[paperclip] saving /home/alex/hundredthings/public/system/photos/21/thumb/casio_fx-82sx.jpg
[paperclip] saving /home/alex/hundredthings/public/system/photos/21/small/casio_fx-82sx.jpg
  SQL (76.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/pages/home
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `fbprofiles`.* FROM `fbprofiles` WHERE (`fbprofiles`.user_id = 30) LIMIT 1
Completed 302 Found in 2961ms
```

I wonder why is this happening?

Update: using Rails.logger gives this output from the server:

```
{:message=>"I've just added Another one to my 111 items list. Check it out: http://111items.com/items/165", :picture=>"http://111items.com/images/rails.png", :link=>"http://111items.com/items/165"}
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving /home/alex/hundredthings/public/system/photos/29/original/crontab.png
[paperclip] saving /home/alex/hundredthings/public/system/photos/29/thumb/crontab.png
[paperclip] saving /home/alex/hundredthings/public/system/photos/29/small/crontab.png
```

So, after_photo_post_process is still called before the attachment is actually saved.

Answer (score 1):

Your output can't say if you right or not.

In your method you output with `puts` but all other output become from `Rails.logger`. And both are not display in same time.

the `puts` command flush immediatly when is call. but the `Rails.logger` bufferize all log and flush only when the request is done.

In your case the `after_photo_post_process` is done before the end of request so it's display before. In you really want see when your code is really call, use `Rails.logger.info` instead of `puts`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, will debug more.

Comment: And updated. Still, attachment is saved after the after_photo_post_process is called.

Comment: it's the normal behavior of after_post_process, after the processing and before the save see the documentation.

Comment: Ok, seems like it. But still, is there any way to catch the event when all the attachments are saved? I sort of need to update facebook wall with the pic after it is actually existing.

Comment: after_create didn't worked, but I'll try the after_save once again.